# X-ray component of solar radiation

Tags: x-rays

What wavelength of x-rays are emitted by the sun and what is the fraction of energy in solar radiation present in the form of x-rays?

Comment: did you try searchin your title? https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/solar-x-ray  https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/objects/sun2.html

Comment: The links do not answer my question.